# preprocessing commands within main

Tags: c, preprocessor-directive

Hello I am trying to find if the user used the command line to pass on specific file names to my program, if the user did not, I will prompt the user to input these file names needed.

Further I must use preprocessing commands to do this.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{
    char original[100] = "";
    char sorted[100] = "";
    if (argc == 0 || argc == 1) 
    { 
        #define PROMPT 1
    }

    FILE * f;
    FILE * s;
    #ifdef PROMPT
    printf("Please input original file name: ");
    scanf("%s", original);
    f = fopen(original, "rw");
    printf("Please input sorted file name: ");
    scanf("%s", sorted);
    s = fopen(sorted, "rw");
    #else
    f = fopen(argv[1], "rw");
    s = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    #endif
}
```

Comment: Preprocessing is done at compile time. You can't use it to check user input.

Comment: Why not use a normal variable?

Comment: _I must use preprocessing commands to do this_ what kind of requirement is this ? Homework ? Maybe you misunderstood something.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use preprossor commands at runtime. That's why it is called ***pre**processor*.

You need this:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{
    char original[100] = "";
    char sorted[100] = "";
    bool prompt = false;

    if (argc == 0 || argc == 1) 
    { 
        prompt = true;
    }

    FILE * f;
    FILE * s;

    if (prompt)
    {
       printf("Please input original file name: ");
       scanf("%s", original);
       f = fopen(original, "rw");
       printf("Please input sorted file name: ");
       scanf("%s", sorted);
       s = fopen(sorted, "rw");
    else
    {
       f = fopen(argv[1], "rw");
       s = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    } 
}
```

Or maybe you want this:

```
#define PROMPT 1

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{
    char original[100] = "";
    char sorted[100] = "";

    FILE * f;
    FILE * s;

#if PROMPT
    printf("Please input original file name: ");
    scanf("%s", original);
    f = fopen(original, "rw");
    printf("Please input sorted file name: ");
    scanf("%s", sorted);
    s = fopen(sorted, "rw");
#else
    if (argc == 0 || argc == 1) 
    { 
        printf("wrong command line arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }
#endif

    f = fopen(argv[1], "rw");
    s = fopen(argv[2], "w");
}
```

With this you can compile two versions of your program. If you compile it with `#define PROMPT 1`, you get the version that always prompts for input, and if you compile it with `#define PROMPT 0` you get the version that always takes command line arguments.

**Side note** (not directly related to your question)

Your test if the number of arguments is correct is wrong: `argc` is at least 1 because it is the number of command line arguments including the name of the command itself, so the test should be:

```
if (argc == 1 || argc == 2)
```

or even better

```
if (argc != 3)
```